# How to findBy Object argument in spring data?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Instead of specifying the field of an object that I want to search by in spring data, I want it to search by all of the fields. E.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private String ssn;}

@Repository
public interface FooDao extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long>{
Foo findByFoo(Foo foo);}
```

Essentially what this does is look at the fields that are not null in a passed foo object and queries by them OR it queries all the fields the way they are, which can be null or not null.

Assume that `Foo` has a lot of fields and trying to write individual queries wouldn't be very elegant.

I also understand that I can dynamically do this myself, but I'd rather not do that if it's already possible.

Comment: Most JPA providers support a `findByExample` mechanism.  I have a [sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-jpa-hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/data/ExtendedJpaRepository.java) that you can look at for creating your own JPA repository implementation that provides a `findByExample` of its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query by example is something not yet provided by Spring Data. However there's a rudimentary [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/150) open for JPA and a more advanced [feature branch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/tree/issue/DATAMONGO-1245) available for Spring Data MongoDB. Please feel free to watch/vote for the related issues [DATAJPA-218](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-218) and [DATAMONGO-1245](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1245).

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of QBE support, the next best solution would be to utilize the QueryDSL support offered by Spring Data. This would allow you to pass a Predicate based on any number of properties of Foo, therefore giving you similar functionality.

Your repository would then look like:

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor {

}
```

The QueryDSL code generator plugin will generate a query object QFoo which you can use to build a Prediate to pass to the inherited findAll(Predicate predicate) method of your repository.

e.g.

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder(QFoo.firstName(eq("John"));
builder.and(QFoo.lastName(eq("John"));

Iterable<Foo> results = fooRepo.findAll(builder);
```

See here for further examples:

http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/core.querydsl.html